# Can the R package configure and configure.win scripts be run interactively?

Tags: r, r-package, rscript

Is there a way to accept user input when running `R CMD INSTALL PATH_TO_SRC.tar.gz`?  This is for a private R package where I'd like to have the user accept a EULA before the installation completes.

I was attempting to accomplish this using the `configure` and `configure.win` files, but it seems that these shells aren't invoked interactively, so I can't use `read` on stdin.

Any thoughts, or workarounds.